# How to copy listbox items to list and compare the list with another

Tags: c#

I have `List<string> myList` and `List<string> myList1` objects: I would like
to compare them and if they are similar I want to pop up a messagebox, but when I click the button it shows nothing.

```
list<string> myList =new list<string>();
list<string> myList1 =new list<string>();          
myList1.Add("a");
myList1.Add("r");
myList1.Add("u");
myList1.Add("y");

foreach (string str in listBox1.Items)
{
    myList.Add(str);
}

if (myList==myList1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Matched");
}
else { MessageBox.Show("Not matched"); }
```

Comment: You should use `SequenceEqual` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Also, could you please clarify what you mean with the term "similar"?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replaying I mean by "similar" matched ,the listbox collection of items are "a" "b" "c" "d" I made a button to copy these items to  a list and called myList then I made another list and add same listbox items to it although they are same items but I am still getting not matched                                 
            bool equal = myList.SequenceEqual(myList1);
            if(equal == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Matched");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not matched");
            }

Comment: It works with me very fine, thank you guys I am very pleased for your quick answering

Answer (score 2):

`List`'s are references, you're trying to compare 2 lists and they are different references. If you want to see if the same items are in the same order:

```
if(myList.SequenceEquals(myList1))
{
     ....
}
```

Or if they could be in a different order:

```
if(myList.All(myList1.Contains))
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: you need implementation  IEquatable<T> interface for each type that collection  you want to compare. It is not best approach,

Comment: @OlegBondarenko the list is of strings - [which implement `IEquatable<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8). Talking about not the best approach - importing a whole json serialization framework to equate 2 lists.....

Comment: also, it is easier to impelement `IEqualityComparer<T>` and pass it to overloaded LINQ methods

Comment: Yes it is doubtless narrow  answer for this question. String is not required this interface implementation. I meant about custom reference types.

Comment: There are no custom reference types in this question. You're answering a question which has not been asked.